# nodemailer error self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

My gmail account also got lesssecureapps status

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: worker_email,
        pass: worker_pass
      }
})
```

when im trying

```
transporter.sendEmail(options)
```

i got an error:

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this brief answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913747/5172977

Basically, it likely has to do with your transport settings.

Here is the example for the development environment with [Ethereal.email](https://ethereal.email/)

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'some-user-name@ethereal.email',
        pass: 'password'
    },
    // === add this === //
    tls : { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});
```